# I am trying to find a movie where some people get to an alien planet with green aliens

Tags: story-identification, movie, aliens

On this planet there are some weird silver colored stuff which can freeze things. The leader of this alien group thing uses on his people from time to time when they don’t follow orders. It’s an animated kids movie

Comment: This is very vague and broad at the moment, check out [How to ask a good story-ID question?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9335/21267) to see if it helps jog your memory so that you can add some more details.

Comment: If you could edit in more plot details that make this identification unique, as well as possible extra details such as when you may have watched it, what channel it may have been on, was it an original production, etc.

Comment: Sounds a bit like Space Chimps to me.

Comment: Ahhh yeah, it is Space Chimps. I recall now. Thank you for the help

Comment: @Taape Glad I could help. Could you accept the answer below. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I definitely think this is *[Space Chimps](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/WesternAnimation/SpaceChimps)*.

> Meanwhile, Zartog forces Titan to tell him more about the Infinity
>   probe. It turns out that the planet's three suns are about to align,
>   and when that happens, the local volcano (which spits out the
>   "freezing" substance Zartog has been using rather than normal lava)
>   will erupt and its flow will destroy the aliens' village (because the
>   building Zartog forced them to build will divert the "lava" their
>   way.) Luna and Ham rescue Titan but find that their ship is actually
>   on automatic pilot (they never really piloted it) and will soon return
>   to Earth on its own. They decide to stay and help the aliens defeat
>   Zartog. The ship leaves without them.

The film's villain uses freezing 'lava' as described above.